# Is this deletion expected to destruct each array object?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Suppose I use a variation of using `new` to return a pointer to an array:

```
class Type { /* ... */ };

typedef Type Type_42[1][42];
Type (*x)[42] = new Type_42;
```

Since I used `new` to create, I use `delete` to destroy:

```
delete x;
```

Is it expected that each of the destructors for the 42 objects will be called?

Comment: Nope, still `delete []`

Comment: @milleniumbug: I think I understand the rationale behind your comment, but do you have a citation?

Comment: It is about impossible to look for a dupe for this because of a sea of *"How can I delete my array of pointers?"* trash. :/

Comment: The interesting thing about this is that it's an array of *one* item. (That one item happens to be an array of 42 subitems, but that's almost irrelevant). Is `auto p = new X[1]` followed by `delete p;` defined behaviour?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`delete[]` must be used for arrays and `delete` for non-arrays. Since `x` is a pointer to an array, you must use `delete[]`. The citation is [expr.delete]/2. The first Note makes this crystal clear.

> If the operand has a class type, the operand is converted to a pointer type by calling the above-mentioned
>   conversion function, and the converted operand is used in place of the original operand for the remainder of
>   this section. In the first alternative (*delete object*), the value of the operand of `delete` may be a null pointer
>   value, a pointer to a non-array object created by a previous new-expression, or a pointer to a subobject (1.8)
>   representing a base class of such an object (Clause 10). If not, the behavior is undefined. In the second
>   alternative (*delete array*), the value of the operand of `delete` may be a null pointer value or a pointer
>   value that resulted from a previous array *new-expression.* If not, the behavior is undefined. [ *Note:* this
>   means that the syntax of the *delete-expression* must match the type of the object allocated by `new`, not
>   the syntax of the *new-expression.* — *end note* ] [ *Note:* a pointer to a `const` type can be the operand of a
>   *delete-expression;* it is not necessary to cast away the constness (5.2.11) of the pointer expression before it
>   is used as the operand of the *delete-expression.* — *end note* ]

Comment: Thanks. I believe the `delete[]` is required because of the `[1]`. The `[42]` still seems to take effect.

Comment: @jxh although the standard requires `delete[] x`, I don't think I've seen `delete x` fail in practice. See http://ideone.com/U9Fd6f for example.

Comment: It is UB, and therefore should never be done. It *seems* to work in this case because it is an array of *one* element. (The fact that this one element is itself a subarray of 42 subelements is almost irrelevant). Because the top-level array is of *one* element, a call to `delete` can  behave the same as a call to `delete[]`, calling the same destructor. It might work equivalently until, of course, the UB demon decides to delete all your files